# Binding a Xpage DominoDocument to a Bean

Tags: xpages, managed-bean

is it possible to bind a DominoDocument directly to a Managed Bean. So that I can have a property in my Bean which holds a reference to the DominoDocument all the time?

Appreciating any suggestions/advices!

Comment: For very easy access you can use the currentDocument object via a variable resolver method (which can be found in the latest Extension Library and in various implementations of JSFUtil)

Comment: Ok, what if I have two datasources?

Comment: You can then use their data source names instead of "currentDocument"

Comment: I don't understand why you want a DominoDocument at all.  If you want to get into ManageBeans then the page should talk directly to the bean or better yet through a pageController.  Then the bean or controller would use the backend document as needed for reading and writing.  I don't see a good use case for keeping a reference to a DominoDocument from inside a bean.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Per mentioned above, the simplest way to do what you want is instead of binding it to a property in your bean, just access it using a method in your bean.

```
public DominoDocument getDominoDocument() {

    // Whatever the data source name is you want to get
    String documentName = "document1";  

    Object o = ExtLibUtil.resolveVariable(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance(), documentName);

    // Double check that it is a DominoDocument
    if (o instanceof DominoDocument) {
        return (DominoDocument) o;
    }

    return null;

}
```

If you are unable to use the Extension Library, then use:

```
public DominoDocument getDominoDocument() {

    // Whatever the data source name is you want to get
    String documentName = "document1";  

    // Get the VariableResolver for Current FacesContext and Resolve the variable
    FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    VariableResolver resolver = facesContext.getApplication().getVariableResolver();
    Object o = resolver.resolveVariable(facesContext, documentName);

    // Double check that it is a DominoDocument
    if (o instanceof DominoDocument) {
        return (DominoDocument) o;
    }

    return null;

}
```

Data Sources are persisted between requests using a slightly different mechanism to persistence of managed beans, so if you bind a Data Source to a managed bean property, there might possibly be complications depending on what sort of persistence mode an application is running in. It might be okay though I am not sure. 
Also there is a complicated DataSource <-> DataContainer <-> DominoDocument ecosystem which the variable resolver knows how to deal with, so it is simplest to just go through the variable resolver when you want to access it.