# How can I get a handle to DataSource (document1) from a Java Bean

Tags: java, xpages, datasource

How can I get a handle to a DataSource on a XPages from a Java Bean and call its Save() method?

The default variable (ID) is 'document1'.

In ServerSide JavaScript, its a variable document1.save(); //pretty simple.

However, in JSF, I think I have to use the component tree facesContext to get a handle to it.

Thoughts?

Comment: See also this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/40635829/785061

Comment: because I see it coming... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9735648/save-method-on-datasource-does-not-fire-querysave-postsave-events :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`document1` is a handle to [a "NotesXspDocument" (in Domino's SSJS)](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSVRGU_9.0.1/com.ibm.designer.domino.api.doc/r_wpdr_xsp_xspdocument_r.html), the specific Java class being [`com.ibm.xsp.model.domino.wrapped.DominoDocument`](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/dw/lotus/Domino-Designer/JavaDocs/DesignerAPIs/com/ibm/xsp/model/domino/wrapped/DominoDocument.html). The easiest way to get a handle on such a defined `document1`, without passing a reference handle via parameter to a method, would be to resolve the variable.

You can use the Extension Library's `ExtLibUtil` method of `resolveVariable(String name)`, pre- 9.0.1_v15 this required a second parameter of the `FacesContext` instance; `resolveVariable(FacesContext ctx, String name)`.

Alternatively, you could skip the `ExtLibUtil` entirely, although I much prefer it and use it regularly, with the following:

```java
DominoDocument myDoc = (DominoDocument) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()
    .getApplication().getVariableResolver()
    .resolveVariable(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance(), "document1");
```

As you can see from the fact that we're resolving the variable, via the user's `FacesContext` instance, `document1` must actually exist/be accessible to the given `FacesContext` instance for this to work. The `ExtLibUtil` method(s) both [are wrappers to the `FacesContext` variable resolver](https://github.com/OpenNTF/XPagesExtensionLibrary/blob/a1746104af1c6dc1b430206678860109dc407832/extlib/lwp/product/runtime/eclipse/plugins/com.ibm.xsp.extlib.core/src/com/ibm/xsp/extlib/util/ExtLibUtil.java#L214-L230).